# 'Invalid column' error from stored procedure query

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem with a query to store results from a stored procedure in a temporary table. See below for a simplified version of the query itself:

```
USE [ADataBaseName]
GO

CREATE TABLE #temp(
SrcUD16 VARCHAR(200))

DECLARE @return_value int 

INSERT INTO #temp(
SrcUD16)

EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[AStoredProcedure]
@PartKey = 100,
@Entity_Name = N'SomeEntityName,
@PeriodDesc = N'QA - 2014',
@CategoryKey = 12

SELECT * FROM #temp

GO
```

The stored procedure creates two other temporary tables to be joined in a Select statement:

```
SELECT SrcUD16 FROM #temp2 LEFT JOIN #temp3
ON #temp2.MinMaxCIC = #temp3.SrcUD15
```

Executing the first statement above will give me the following error:
'Invalid column name 'SrcUD16'

However, manually executing the stored procedure does yield the expected results for the field SrcUD16.  I can also change the fieldname from SrcUD16 to SrcUD15 which results in a working query albeit incorrect column heading (i.e. ScrUD16 data with 'SrcUD15' as heading).

I strongly suspect this error has something to do with the order in which the temp tables are created and what the query recognizes as allowed field headings. Perhaps someone with better understanding has soem pointers for me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #temp
GO

Comment: The GO Statement following the DROP seems to do the trick